# Generate external link to Google search result at Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

Hello I am generating layout with an external link to Google search result with inserted variables (that look like #SOMEWORDSASTAGS) I am using Jekyll syntax and HTML together, see:

```
<p class="one">#<u><a href=”https://www.google.com/search?q=#{{ page.shortname }}”>{{ page.shortname }}</a></u> ({{ page.content | number_of_words }})</b></p>
```

I want Google to search anything with inserted hashtag #SOMEWORDSASTAGS created by #{{ page.shortname }}

As result I am getting the link that includes my_domain in the beginning and therefore don't work correctly.

```
https://my_domain/%E2%80%9Dhttps://www.google.com/search?q=#SOMEWORDSASTAGS
```

See [sample page here](https://indexmod.gq/galinskaya-olga) click link on left bottom "GALINSKAYA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **_includes/footer.html**, you're quoting your url with inappropriate characters : `”` (charcode 8221), but your are supposed to quote with simple quote `'` (charcode 39) or double quote `"` (charcode 34).

`”https://www.google.com/search?q=#{{ page.shortname }}”` fail, but

`"https://www.google.com/search?q=#{{ page.shortname }}"` works.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but there is something wrong with Google syntax - we have strange ending of search line https://www.google.com/webhp#ГАЛИНСКАЯ and empty results window

Comment: Thank you, David!

Comment: But, I wanted to include a hashtag symbol in the search request — #ГАЛИНСКАЯ. I have try to quote it as exact collocation — "#ГАЛИНСКАЯ" but there is some conflict of the syntaxes... Thank in advance for any trick!

Comment: You'd better ask a new question with "google-search" tag. Comments are not suppose to answer side questions.